# Encountering error on Editing the SharePoint Site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have full control for my SharePoint site and when I try to edit the page .I am facing error as below can any one help me how can I solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: what is the SP version?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you need to check if you have any custom webparts or third party webparts on that page. They obviously contain an update panel that is not done correctly.

in order to edit the page you need to remove the offending webpart first:

at the end of the url just add the following `?contents=1`

that will go into edit mode to show you a list of webparts on that page, check the webpart that you want to remove and click delete.

if its a custom page that you created (aspx) than you need to goto where ever its stored and download a copy. You then need to ammend the updatepanel by placing it within another updatepanel as stated in the error or remove it for now. Reupload the aspx page to same location and publish and then edit in sharepoint!